# "Я не робот". Запретить выполнение функции, пока не поставлена галочка

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, recaptcha

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такая форма. После заполнения всех полей и галочки `Я не робот`, кнопка `Отправить` становится активной. Но дело в том, что можно просто заполнить поля и не проходить капчу, действие сработает всё равно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы пока кнопка неактивна, при нажатии на нее ничего не происходило?

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key" data-callback="verifyRecaptchaCallback" data-expired-callback="expiredRecaptchaCallback"></div>
  <input class="form-control d-none" data-recaptcha="true" required="required" data-error="Please complete the Captcha">
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div id="success"></div>
<div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xl" id="sendMessageButton">Отправить</button>
</div>
```

```html
$(function() {

  $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
      // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
      // get values from FORM
      var name = $("input#name").val();
      var phone = $("input#phone").val();
   var theme = $("select#theme").val();
      var message = $("textarea#message").val();
      var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
      // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
      if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
      }
      $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
      $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
      $.ajax({
        url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          name: name,
          phone: phone,
          theme: theme,
          message: message
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
          // Success message
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
          $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append("<strong>Ваша заявка успешно отправлена. В течении 5 минут, Вам перезвонят по указанному номеру!</strong>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append('</div>');
          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function() {
          // Fail message
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Извините, похоже, мой почтовый сервер не отвечает. Пожалуйста, попробуйте обратиться напрямую по адресу: "));
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        complete: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
          }, 1000);
        }
      });
    },
    filter: function() {
      return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
  });

  $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
  });
});

/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
  $('#success').html('');
});
```

Я пробовал изменить `$this = $("#sendMessageButton");` на `$this = $("#sendMessageButton").on("click", "td:not(.disabled)", handler);`, но тогда вообще ничего не происходит.

p.s извините, если код выложил неправильно.

upd:

```html
<?php
// ваш секретный ключ
$secret = 'key';
// однократное включение файла autoload.php (клиентская библиотека reCAPTCHA PHP)
require_once (dirname(__FILE__).'/recaptcha/autoload.php');
// если в массиве $_POST существует ключ g-recaptcha-response, то...
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
  // создать экземпляр службы recaptcha, используя секретный ключ
  $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
  // получить результат проверки кода recaptcha
  $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  // если результат положительный, то...
  if ($resp->isSuccess()){
    // действия, если код captcha прошёл проверку
    //...
  } else {
    // иначе передать ошибку
    $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
    $data['error-captcha']=$errors;
    $data['msg']='Код капчи не прошёл проверку на сервере';
    $data['result']='error';
  }
 
} else {
  //ошибка, не существует ассоциативный массив $_POST["send-message"]
  $data['result']='error';
}
```

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы не забываете проверять капчу на сервере?

Comment: @andreymal, обновил пост

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался!

```
var btnEnabled = $this = $("#sendMessageButton").hasClass('disabled');
```

и соответственно, если `btnEnabled == true`, то `return false;`